# How to run an SAP GUI script from AHK

Tags: macros, autohotkey, sap-gui

Created a script in SAP and can run it via a macro in excel.
This is the code that runs it in Excel Macro.
Shell "WScript ""C:\FVFR\Script2.vbs"""
This is the actual script,

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[21]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").select
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[1,0]").select
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-    SELFLAG[1,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt/SIE/SMS_DXCAUSE-ISSUE_TYPE").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt/SIE/SMS_DXCAUSE-ISSUE_TYPE").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 4
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/lbl[1,4]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/lbl[1,4]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[5]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlEDIT_MELD/shellcont/shell").setSelectionIndexes 0,26
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTASK_LONG_TEXT/shellcont/shell").setSelectionIndexes 0,26
```

I want to be able to use this macro in AHK and I have tried
Run, Shell "WScript ""C:\FVFR\Script2.vbs"""
or just Run, C:\FVFR\Script2.vbs    but it will not work at all or it just opens the script code.
Would like it if when I press ^!g:: then the SAP marco would run.
Not very savy with AHK so require assistance.

***UPDATE***
Was able to get to work with,
Run, WScript.exe "C:\FVFR\Script2.vbs"